# Enable chainability in a Javascript object like jQuery

Tags: javascript

I've a question about chainability, look at this code:

```
document.getElementById('menu').fadeIn(200, function(){ //callback });
```

How can i make this without jQuery?

Note: the name *fadeIn()* and *fadeOut()* are for example, there are not the jQuery functions.

Comment: You'll have to implement your own (simplified or expanded) mechanism like jQuery's to do it.  Another approach would be to use DOM extensions like the Prototype library.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> "Method chaining is a common technique for invoking multiple method
>   calls in object-oriented programming languages. Each method returns an
>   object (possibly the current object itself), allowing the calls to be
>   chained together in a single statement.A method chain is also
>   known as a train wreck due to an increasing amount of methods stacked
>   after another in one line."

```
//Create an object which contains functions
var obj={
        alert : function(txt){
                alert(txt);
                return this   //return itself
        },
        confirm :function(txt){
                confirm(txt);
                return this   //return itself
        }
}

//Now you can chain as much as you want
obj.alert("This").alert("is").confirm("called").alert("chaining.");
```

Source:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining#JavaScript

Comment: i don't want to make an object. I want to create a new method for the document.getElementById i've read something similar here [link](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/prototypal-chainability/) but i can't "attach" the method to the object.

Answer (score 1):

To allow chainability your methods have to return the containing object (and, sometimes, provide a callback mechanism to manage some return data):

```
var chainable ={
        doSomething : function(input, callback){
          //do something with the input
          var output = input;
          if (callback && typeof(callback) === "function") {
              callback(output);
          }
          return this;
        }
}

    chainable.doSomething('test', function(data) {
      alert(data);
    })
    .doSomething('anotherString');
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. i've understand the callback management